# Can I load a Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static vector from a pointer

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, hmatrix

I want to pass double-arrays to/from a Fortran77 library with `Foreign.Marshal.Array`, but in my Haskell code, I want to use statically sized vectors from `Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static`. My minimal example attempt is the below.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import           Data.Proxy
import           Foreign.Marshal.Array
import           Foreign.Ptr
import           GHC.TypeNats
import           Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static
import           Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data hiding (R,vector)

store :: (KnownNat n) => R n -> IO (Ptr Double)
store = newArray  . toList . unwrap


load :: (KnownNat n) => Ptr Double -> IO (R n)
load p = do
    let k = fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
    doubles <- peekArray k p 
    return (vector doubles :: R n)

main = do
    let a = vector [1,5,2] :: R 3
    print a
    ptr <- store a
    print ptr
    b <- (load ptr) :: IO (R 3)
    print b
```

The `store` function works, but the `load` does not compile. It seems that the `n` in the function body is not matched to the `n` in the type declaration. Is it something about existentials -- a topic I have not grasped? I tried the `ScopedTypeVariables` but it did not help me. How to proceed?

Comment: This should in principle be easy, because the “static” types are anyways just phantom-annotated wrappers around dynamic ones. `hmatrix` doesn't seem to expose the constructors in any way, however there is a `Generic` instance that could probably be exploited.

Comment: That sounds good, but I don't know how I would do that.  Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I flailed around wildly, and the following code fixed it.

I use the `ScopedTypeVariables` and an explicit `forall n.` in the the signature of `load`. I still have no real clue on why it works. So I'll refrain from makring this as an answer, in hope of someone else actually *explaining* a solution.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import           Data.Proxy
import           Foreign.Marshal.Array
import           Foreign.Ptr
import           GHC.TypeNats
import           Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static
import           Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data hiding (R,vector)

store :: (KnownNat n) => R n -> IO (Ptr Double)
store = newArray  . toList . unwrap


load :: forall n. (KnownNat n) => Ptr Double -> IO (R n)
load p = do
    let k = fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
    doubles <- peekArray k p 
    return (vector doubles :: R n)

main = do
    let a = vector [1,5,2] :: R 3
    print a
    ptr <- store a
    print ptr
    b <- (load ptr) :: IO (R 3)
    print b
```